# Pipeline with and without data forwarding

Tags: mips, mips32

I'm confused about comparing number of stall cycles of pipelining with and without data forwarding.

I'll use an example to illustrate my question:

For the following MIPS instructions:

> I1: add $t1, $t2, $t3
>
> I2: sub $t2, $t1, $t2

Which of the following pipeline is true? ("S" indicates one clock cycle stall)

```
I1 IF ID EX MEM WB

I2    IF  S  S  S  ID EX MEM WB


I1 IF ID EX MEM WB

I2    IF  S  S  ID EX MEM WB
```

To be more specific, when data forwarding is not applied, does Instruction Decode happen in the same clock as Write Back, or one clock after?